# Android How to Identify Listview Button clicked event from outside adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview which having button as a item.

[image]

I want to set Listener to this button. Currently im using following code in the adapter to Identify it.

```
  holder.editDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //rowItem.getUserID();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });
```

Is there anyway to Identify this button onclick event outside adapter.(in the Main.class) like

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   });
```

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Tells more about why you want to do that. Do you want to access the activity from your adapter?

Comment: yes..thats the thing i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Activity` is an `ListActivity` you can use `onItemClick` :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// TODO
}
```

Comment: its a Dialog Fragment Activity.

Answer (score 7):

You can create an interface for that. Pass your interface to your adapter and call it when you click the button.

```
public interface onDoneClick{
    void onClick(View v, int position);
}
```

In this interface we are going to pass the position on the adapter as well as the view.

Next add the interface to your **adapter's constructor** and save it in a field. For example:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MyObject> objects,onDoneClick listener ) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Now that we have our listener just call it on your **holder.editDetails** click listener:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         mListener.onClick(v,position);//where position is the position in the adapter
      }
```

Next on your **activity** when you create your adapter just pass the listener to it:

```
    new MyAdapter(this, 0, myobjectList, new onDoneClick() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position) {
            //whatever you want to do.
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but this is sooooo useful. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method in your Activity like:

```
public void setListenerToButton(Button b){
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //rowItem.getUserID();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and inside getView

```
((YourActivity)getContext()).setListenerToButton(holder.editDetails);
```

Comment: can you please explain little bit more

Comment: Im  using DialogFragment class.how should i cast it?

Comment: You have a DialogFragment containing a ListView?

Comment: Ok in this case i think that @Pedro Oliveira solution is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can make the adapter an inner class of your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView;
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(...));
}

private void activityMethod() {
    // Do something
}

/* Your custom adapter */
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...

        holder.editDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                activityMethod();
            }
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

Then you are able to call your activity from your the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This listener gives you several informations about the clicked view:

```
public abstract void  onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

[Doku](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

A nice tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event

But you set the listener for the whole view, not just for the button.