# How to get Id of ChildView Items of ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using ExpandapbeListView its work perfect all expand and collapse but I just want to update only particular child item here when I click on plus value should be update in EditText and I don't want to use **notifyDatasetChanged()**  Just want to update only particular field and also i should able to update EditText directly. It can have multiple child item.

Ex: Colgate may have multiple child Item like 100gm,200gm,300gm

So when I click on Plus It should able to get Id of EditText and Update Quantity

[image]

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(int productPos, int weightPos, boolean b, View plusMinusView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (plusMinusView == null) {

            csHolder = new ChildHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            plusMinusView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_products_plus_minus_design, null);
        }
        csHolder.minQty             = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitMinQtyTxt);
        csHolder.totalPriceTxt      = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitTotalPriceTxt);
        csHolder.weightTxt          = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitWeightTxt);
        csHolder.unitPrice          = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitUnitPriceTxt);
        csHolder.totalTaxTxt        = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitTotalTaxTxt);
        csHolder.netPriceTxt        = (TextView) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitNetPriceTxt);
        csHolder.orderQtyEdit       = (CustomEditText) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_orderQtyTxt);
        csHolder.plusTxt            = (RelativeLayout) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_plusTxtLay);
        csHolder.minusTxt           = (RelativeLayout) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_minusTxtLay);


        plusMinusView.setTag(productPos + "_" + weightPos);

        String tag = "weight_" + productPos + "_" + weightPos;
        csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setTag(tag);
        csHolder.plusTxt.setTag(tag);
        csHolder.minusTxt.setTag(tag);


        //csHolder.plusTxt.setOnClickListener(weightClick);
        //csHolder.minusTxt.setOnClickListener(weightClick);

        final View finalPlusMinusView = plusMinusView;
        csHolder.plusTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setText("5");
            }
        });

        if(!csStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("DRAFT")) {
            csHolder.plusTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            csHolder.minusTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            csHolder.plusTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            csHolder.minusTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setEnabled(true);
        }

        try
        {
            csHolder.orderQtyEdit.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(csHolder.orderQtyEdit));

            JSONObject weighObj = csMainArr.getJSONObject(productPos).getJSONArray("weights").getJSONObject(weightPos);
            if(weighObj.has("unit"))
            {
                csHolder.weightTxt.setText(weighObj.getString("unit"));
            }

            if (weighObj.has("order_qty") == false)
                weighObj.put("order_qty", "0");

            if (weighObj.has("sell_price") == false)
                weighObj.put("sell_price", "0");

            if (weighObj.has("order_qty") == false)
            {
                csHolder.totalPriceTxt.setText("0.00");
                csHolder.totalTaxTxt.setText("0.00");
                csHolder.netPriceTxt.setText("0.00");
            }
            else {
                int         qty         = 0;
                double      sellPrice   = 0.00;
                float       tax         = 0f;

                double   totalPrice  = 0.00;
                double   totalTax    = 0.00;
                double   netPrice    = 0.00;
                if(csStatus.equals("DRAFT")) {
                    qty = Integer.parseInt(weighObj.getString("order_qty"));
                    sellPrice = weighObj.getDouble("sell_price");
                }
                else
                {
                    qty = Integer.parseInt(weighObj.has("qty") ? weighObj.getString("qty"):"0");
                    sellPrice = weighObj.getDouble("unit_price");
                }
                tax         = Float.parseFloat(csMainArr.getJSONObject(productPos).has("tax") ? csMainArr.getJSONObject(productPos).getString("tax") : "0");


                totalPrice  = qty*sellPrice;
                totalTax    = (totalPrice*tax)/100;
                netPrice    = totalPrice + totalTax;

                csHolder.totalPriceTxt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.format("%.2f",totalPrice));
                csHolder.totalTaxTxt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.format("%.2f",totalTax));
                csHolder.netPriceTxt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.format("%.2f",netPrice));
            }

            csHolder.orderQtyEdit.isValueChangeMySelf = true;
            if(csStatus.equals("DRAFT"))
                csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setText(weighObj.getString("order_qty"));
            else
                csHolder.orderQtyEdit.setText(weighObj.has("qty")?weighObj.getString("qty"):"0");

            /*if(weightPos == iClickedItem) {
                csHolder.orderQtyEdit.requestFocus();

            }
            else {
                csHolder.orderQtyEdit.clearFocus();
            }*/

            if(csStatus.equals("DRAFT"))
                csHolder.unitPrice.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.format("%.2f",weighObj.has("sell_price")?weighObj.getDouble("sell_price") : 0.00));
            else
                csHolder.unitPrice.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.format("%.2f",weighObj.has("unit_price")?weighObj.getDouble("unit_price") : 0.00));

            csHolder.minQty.setText(weighObj.has("min_order_qty")?weighObj.getString("min_order_qty"):"0");


            //View line = (View) plusMinusView.findViewById(R.id.orderProducts_submitDividerLine);
            //if(isLast)
            //  line.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }


        return plusMinusView;
    }
```

Comment: inside your getChildView() , find your edittext by findViewById() and set click listner on that edit text.

Comment: Ya i have done with all those things but how can i get id when i click on plus and minus button

Comment: same way you find your plus and minus button by findViewById() ,and inside click of this button ,you have already position of your edittext ,you can use that for update it.

Comment: Its not a single item I may have multiple child I have tried ur Idea In that way if i have 10 child then its updating last one only

Comment: you have to use interface in this.

Comment: I'm not so expert in custom interface ,but let me try.

Comment: plz refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524855/android-how-to-identify-listview-button-clicked-event-from-outside-adapter and set interface in adapter